# Linux backup a folder by each

Tags: linux, shell-script, backup, tar

I have a folder `/home/software`, with some sub folders

```
/home/software/game
/home/software/photo
/home/software/ebook
...
```

I want to create tar backup including the date for each sub-folder so I will end up with files like:

```
game-20151013.tar.gz
photo-20151013.tar.gz
ebook-20151013.tar.gz
...
```

What's the best way to do that, and to the delete any of those backups that is more than 10 days old?

Comment: Have you looked into `rsync`? It has the compression and pruning that you are looking for.

Comment: no , i not looking for rsync.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to reinvent the wheel. There are lots of (free and open) backup programs out there that do the job (dar, attic, obnam, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that does what you have asked for:

```
ls /home/software/ | while read d
 do
  tar czf "/home/software/$d-$(date +%y%m%d).tar.gz" "/home/software/$d"
 done
find /home/software -type f -name '*.tar.gz' -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \;
```

or

```
cd /home/software/
ls | while read d
 do
  tar czf "$d-$(date +%y%m%d).tar.gz" "$d"
 done
find . -type f -name '*.tar.gz' -mtime +10 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: show the error:   tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

Comment: change directory inside /home/software/ and run commands in place ! see answer editted :)